# Create new project with Eclipse by using GIT

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I would like to open project that is located in remote git repository. I do File->New->Project and expect wizard something like "project from GIT". But there is no such selection. How to ask eclipse create project and clone project to it?
EGit plugin is installed.
[image]

Comment: _File > Import...: Git > Project from Git_

Answer (score 0):

The manual has a section "[Starting from existing Git Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories)"

> In order to work with the content of a Git repository in the Eclipse workbench, the contained files and folders must be imported as projects.
>
> In principle, this import can be done using the generic "New Project" or "Import..." wizards, since the working directory of a Git Repository is just a normal directory in the local file system.
>   However, the newly created projects would still have to be shared manually with Git. The "Import Projects from Git" wizard integrates project import and sharing and also offers some extra convenience.
>
> Starting the import wizard
>
> To start the wizard click `Import > Git > Projects from Git`.
>
> If you started in a clean workspace, the first page will display an empty list:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/5/5a/Egit-0.9-import-projects-select-repository.png]

> if you already have a repository in your local file system, for example because you have cloned it earlier, you created it from scratch or you copied it from somewhere else.
>   Click `Add...`; and select a directory in the local file system.
>   Press `Search` to trigger a scan for Git repositories contained in this directory.
>   If Git repositories are found, they will be listed and you can select repositories to add:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/ed/Egit-0.11-import-projects-add-dialog.png]